# Суффикс -ик- в прилагательных

Tags: словообразование, морфология, морфемика, прилагательные

В словах *великий* и *толикий* выделяется один и тот же суффикс -ик-. Он образует прилагательные от других прилагательных, ср.: вел-ий > вел-ик-ий; *тол-ий > тол-ик-ий. Как сформулировать его значение? В чем разница между производящими и производными словами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь приходится рассуждать об устаревших словах, чьё словообразование происходило ещё в праславянском языке. У корня *velъ/*volъ (желание, воля)(в индоевропейском хотеть, желать) позже появилось значение СИЛА (чья-то воля), от него velьjь - сильный, крепкий, мощный. Одновременно образовалось прилагательное великий: вел(ий)+ суфф.-ик-, где -ик- увеличительный суффикс (как уменьшит.-оньк-/-еньк-), вот и получилось великий - очень большой, очень сильный(сверх меры).

Толикий - столь многочисленный. Толика - мера, какое-то определённое количество + -ик- - больше меры, много больше. Получается Толикий - больше меры, многий, очень большой, великий.

Есть ещё старославянизм селикий - селико •стар., церк. столький(се- это, то, так); толикий; столь многий. Толковый словарь Даля. ( 1863- 1866)

Так что -ик- здесь -устаревший  суффикс со значением увеличения, усиления 
 качества. Сейчас он не используется..